# How to call the django save method on an update

Tags: python, django

I would like to "disable" an `update()` method by essentially forcing it to call a `save` on every object in django. How would I do that? Currently I have:

```
  class HandleQuerySet(QuerySet):
      def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
          for x in self:
              x.save()
```

But this doesn't seem to be passing the args to the save method -- as in, it doesn't save anything. How would I properly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to update the fields that are passed in? You would need to update `x` with the arguments passed as `kwargs`. One way to do this is with the help of `setattr`:

```
class HandleQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for x in self:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                setattr(x, k, v)
            x.save()
```

Comment: thanks, I tried doing something like that, but then I get errors like `TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'master_id'`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thanks, that works (the other approach would be to call the `super` of the save).